# Leitura de arquivo com formato fixo com linhas de diferentes padrões

Tags: python, pandas

Estou usando o pandas para a leitura de um arquivo txt com formato fixo, entretanto, o arquivo tem um tamanho de coluna para as linhas que começam com a letra A e outro tamanho para as linhas que começam com a letra B. Em VBA foi fácil implementar, pois como ele lia linha por linha, eu coloquei um `if` para testar o primeiro digito e ler a linha de um jeito ou de outro, entretanto em Python não sei como fazer.

```
    import pandas as pd
    largurasColunasTipoA = [26, 25,25,25,4,30,14,30,14,257]
    largurasColunasTipoB = [14, 4, 15, 10, 17, 17, 17, 17, 10, 4, 4, 6, 298]
    
    caminhoTotal = caminho + arquivo

    baseLida = pd.read_fwf(caminhoTotal, header=None, widths=largurasColunasTipoA, encoding='unicode_escape')
```

Comment: Você pode ler o arquivo com `read_csv` bastando para isso que a primeira linha contenha todos os nomes de colunas possíveis. Caso não possa nome de colunas, use `header=None`

Comment: Duas pergutas 1 ) O que o VBA faz? gera duas tabelas diferentes (duas tabelas)  ou completa as colunas "vazias"  das colunas tipo A (mais curtas) com valores 0 ou NaN; 2 ) Voce quer implementar a mesma estratégia como em VBA "if" ou apenas uma solucao. Talvez ajudasse se voce colocasse um exemplo to output esperado. Com seus comentários consigo gerar uma resposta rápida pra voce